# Flask returning only the last value or first value using boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, boto3

I'm using below script to generate the list of specific IAM Role Names which works perfectly fine on console and list IAM Role Names as expected.

```
import boto3 
import logging
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger('LUCIFER')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def main():
    try:
        client = boto3.client('iam')
        roles = client.list_roles(PathPrefix='/', MaxItems=1000)
        for i in roles["Roles"]:
            if "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML".lower() in str(i).lower():
                logger.info(i["RoleName"])
        return i["RoleName"]
    
    except ClientError:
        logger.exception("Couldn't list roles for the account")
        raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But when I try to serve this script via below flask script it only returns last value.

```
from flask import Flask
from main import main

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    return main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

Any hints? Do I need another html template to serve it?

My end goal is to serve it via Vue.js frontend framework, any ideas on it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In your main, you return only the last `i`'s RoleName (but log them all). You need to save valid `i`s or valid `RoleName`s to a list and return a whole list.

Comment: I tried to do that but flask finally complains that it cannot serve the list, it should either string or dict or tuple. 

```TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.```

Comment: That's because it doesn't know the response code - for strings, it's assumed to be 200, all other types pass it directly `return main(), 200` should be good - it would be a tuple containing your content and 200 status code it expects. Or wrap it directly in Response, as it said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably confusing it with the output you are logging to console.
Just the last value is returned from `main()`, you are doing nothing with it when running on console.

Actually return a list of the values, this also fixes an error if `roles["Roles"]` is an emtpy list, since `i` would not be set:

```
def main():
    try:
        client = boto3.client('iam')
        roles = client.list_roles(PathPrefix='/', MaxItems=1000)
        result = []
        for i in roles["Roles"]:
            if "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML".lower() in str(i).lower():
                logger.info(i["RoleName"])
                result.append(i["RoleName"])
        return result
    
    except ClientError:
        logger.exception("Couldn't list roles for the account")
        raise
```

---

Update: return JSON list

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    rolenames = main()
    return jsonify(rolenames)
```

Comment: I tried to do that but flask finally complains that it cannot serve the list, it should either string or dict or tuple.

```TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.
```

Comment: I deleted my answer in favor of @ivvija's as their answer is closer.   What you need to do is return a template with the list as a parameter

Comment: @AzizZoaib i updated it with a simple example of `flask.jsonify` to return a JSON string

Comment: Yes, that works. Now my end end goal is to serve it via Vue.js